# Why does this work under Ruby 1.9.3 and not under 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a custom Form Builder in Rails and i've been following this great Rails Cast video (http://railscasts.com/episodes/311-form-builders?view=asciicast).

Ryan uses a line like this:

```
<%= form_for @project, builder: BootstrapFormBuilder do |f| %>
```

But under 1.8.7 this bombs out with a cryptic error message.

What changed in Ruby 1.9.3 that makes this now work?

By the way, the following *does* work in 1.8.7, but why?

```
<%= form_for(@project, :builder => BootstrapFormBuilder) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9+ allows the new hash syntax `key: value` also supporting the existing `:key => value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What changed in Ruby 1.9.3 that makes this now work?

There is a new syntax for `Hash` literals whose keys are `Symbol`s which are valid identifiers. Instead of

```
{ :foo => 'bar', :baz => 42 }
```

You can now also write

```
{ foo: 'bar', baz: 42 }
```

This syntax was introduced in 1.9.0.

> By the way, the following does work in 1.8.7, but why?

Because that's the same thing, just written using a different syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The hash syntax has been extended to let users use a JavaScript like style.

```
# Old syntax
old_hash = { :name => 'Ruby', :influences => ['Perl', 'Python', 'Smalltalk'] }

# New syntax (Ruby 1.9 only)
new_hash = { name: 'Ruby', influences: ['Perl', 'Python', 'Smalltalk'] }
```

http://peepcode.com/blog/2011/rip-ruby-hash-rocket-syntax

Answer (score 1):

The hash syntax changed in Ruby 1.9. In all versions of Ruby you can use `key => value`, but Ruby 1.9 has a new `key: value` syntax. This is why your second example works, but the first doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this part:

```
builder: BootstrapFormBuilder
```

This creates a hash, but the syntax is only allowed in Ruby 1.9+. Before, to create a hash, you had to do

```
:builder => BootstrapFormBuilder
```

Which is why the second line works in 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.9 introduced an alternative hash syntax:

```
# Ruby 1.8 and 1.9
h = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }

# Ruby 1.9 only
h = { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

It should be noted that `a:` is just a syntactic sugar for `:a =>`, that is `a` is still a symbol.

Comment: there is a nice [blog post](http://logicalfriday.com/2011/06/20/i-dont-like-the-ruby-1-9-hash-syntax/) whose author does not like the new syntax, and gives good arguments